# Obtaining elements and attributes from JSONArray using Java

Tags: java, xml, json

I have the following JSONArray:

```
[
    {
        "test":{
            "page":"Apple",
            "ms":"234"}
        },
    {   
        "check":{
            "page":"Apple",
            "ms":"234"
        }
    }
]
```

Here say "test" and "check" are the parent elements and there will be quite a lot of elements like this. So i have to loop through each and every one of them and have to get the child element of the if it matches the name. Im so new to JSON, so have no idea how it works. Below is the simple algorithm how it should work.

```
Loop through each elements:
    switch(parent_name){
       case "test":
          get child information like:
              if(attribute == "page"){
                  get text which is "Apple"
              }
          break;
       default:
          break;
    }
```

This is how it should work. I have tried in XML. But not JSON. Below is the xml code:

```
Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();

if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element ele = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    switch(ele.getNodeName()){
                            case "Click":
                                ele.getAttributes().getNamedItem("object").getNodeValue();
                                break;
                            case "Open":
                                ele.getAttributes().getNamedItem("page").getNodeValue();
                                break;
                            case "CheckElementPresent":
                        ele.getAttributes().getNamedItem("object").getNodeValue();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add, Im using "json.simple" as json lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as :

`JSONArray jsonArray = data; //here data is JSON array you are getting from any source`

You need to add  JSONException`because when we get`JSONObject`from`JSONArray` it can throw error so.

then just iterate it :

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++ ){
      try {
           JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           if( ! object.isNull("test") ){
                JSONObject j = object.getJSONObject("test");
                System.out.println(j.getString("page"));
                System.out.println(j.getString("ms"));
            }
            if( ! object.isNull("check") ){
                JSONObject j = object.getJSONObject("check");
                System.out.println(j.getString("page"));
                System.out.println(j.getString("ms"));
            }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Still problem then post me.

Comment: Is it for json.simple. Because it gives errors. i.e i have to use size() isintead of length. I fixed few.But not everything. So could make it to work.

Comment: @Vithushan : I am using `org.json` and works fine for me. You just need to replicate your code with mine and ll work fine.

Comment: oh. Are you telling that if i change the lib to org.json it will work. Because creating that JSONArray is not done by me. It was done by someone else which is a complex program. So i want to know whether it will work if i change the lib to yours and get that JSONArray and work with your code? Will it collapse with different libs? Thanks for the rep

Comment: @Vithushan : Yes it ll work, I am using same code. I have lots of code that is used to manipulate `JSON` & `XML`. I am using `xml`  library for `XML`.

Comment: No was i asked is whether both lib compactibile with each other and it is not. I tried it out. ANd made the change and corrected the compile errors. Now im getting runtime errors. Here is the error:

org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["test"] not a string.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:644)
 at com.command.Main.main(Main.java:34)

This is shooting at "if(object.getString("test") != null){" line. What should i do?

Comment: remove the condition then try : `JSONObject j = object.getJSONObject("test");` then `System.out.println(j.getString("page"));` comment other lines and just check is it working or not ? Post me the result.

Comment: The reason might be because it is not text inside that. It is another object, right. So i thing getString wont work i guess.

Comment: I also think so.. So get it in new `JSONObject` then again try using `getString()`

Comment: Finally that return "Apple". Thanks alot. Now how to check whether that first object has the value "test" or "check"

Comment: try `if(object.getString("").equals("test")){ }`, post me.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject[""] not found.

Comment: dude this works: can you add this and post an answer?

if( ! object.isNull("test") ){
        // do your stuff 
       }

Comment: I have updated the answer, still some lack then you can also edit it.

Comment: @Vithushan -Hey I have updated answer with updated code & working fine. Now can accept the answer if you want. Thank You.

Comment: Hmm.. Keep Smiling.. :)